# mysql query to subtract from table in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: table design]

Above is my table design, I need to subtract value from "unit" field. I used this query

```
update table SET unit=unit-3 where product='Ghee' ORDER BY date DESC
```

The above query makes "unit" field values in `<minus>`, if unit of ghee field is less than 3..

**Here is the scenario**

```
unit   product   date  
1      ghee      2013-06-12 
3      ghee      2013-06-14
```

I need to subtract 3 unit from product GHEE

If I use this query

```
update table SET unit=unit-3 where product='Ghee' ORDER BY date DESC
```

I need to subtract from descending order.

Comment: what is the point in subtracting from descending order? anyways records update you are making is independent of other record? can you update your requirement? it is not clear..

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this maybe?

```
UPDATE table SET 
    unit=unit-(
       SELECT TOP 1 unit 
       FROM table WHERE product = 'Ghee' ORDER BY UNIT DESC
    )
where product='Ghee'
```

It will remove "3" or what ever the highiest value in units is for the given product.